# Game Center sandbox losing scores

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm testing Game Center leaderboards in my App and my scores seem to be disappearing after a while.  I had 3 different sandbox accounts creating high scores one night, and then the next morning, they were all gone.  All my categories were empty.

Does Apple reset these periodically?  Or is there something else going one?  Are there several sandbox servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this turned out to be an Apple bug.  I filed a bug report and it was fixed a day later.

Comment: Can you share the Apple bug details? I'm having the same exact issue.