# Game Center sandbox leaderboards wont show scores other than local score

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, leaderboard

I've been trying to get Game Center leaderboards working in a new iOS project for 3 days now.

The sandbox leaderboard only shows the user's local score, and not "all scores".

I can successfully post scores to leaderboards, and have done so from 4 different accounts, however the leaderboard only shows the user's local score.

Also each day, the leaderboards reset and show "no scores" for each user account. They've been doing this for the past 3 days.

Any idea what the issue might be? I've successfully submitted scores from 4 accounts across simulator + 2 devices.

Comment: Also one more tidbit-- if Acct1 and Acct2 are friends, they can see each other scores, but these scores get reset each day and the next day the leaderboard says "never played" for each user and shows 0 scores.

Comment: Need some code to work with I think.

Answer (score 0):

partially appears to be a bug. I myself have only used game center once and didn't test it beyond the day i got had everything working or once again before final build so i wouldn't have experience this next day bug but apparently you aren't alone as you can see in this other post link... [Game Center sandbox losing scores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261994/game-center-sandbox-losing-scores)

as for your local score showing up you may have to post some code or provide more information for a answer for that because you say everything is working except that then that is a little strange because you either are or aren't getting information from the game center server it shouldn't be getting local values unless it's bad code for that code line on your end.